# Number theory question about powers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all solutions in positive integers to the following equation where p is a prime number:

$m^3 + 7p^2 = 2^n$

I tried doing it mod $7$, and then using difference of cubes, but now I am stuck. Can anyone help me?

I was given a hint:

Consider both sides of the given equation modulo $7$. That is, consider what the possible
remainders could be for perfect cubes are when divided by $7$. Do the same for powers of $2$. This
should allow you to deduce something about $n$. After this, rewrite the equation as $7p^2 = 2^n - m^3$
and see if you can factor the right hand side. Note that since p is prime, there aren’t too many ways
of factoring $7p^2$.

I followed the hint, and got $7p^2=(2^k-m)(2^{2k}+2^km+m^2)$, which I split into three cases, $(1,7p^2),(7,p^2),(p,7p)$.

Thank you!

Comment: For what exactly are you solving?

Comment: Show your work for what you get when following the hints you were given.

Comment: $2n$ or $2^n{}$?

Comment: $2^n$, sorry, i edited it now.

Answer (score 2):

Full proof that there is only one solution $m=1, p=3, n=6$. $2^n\mod 7$ is $1,2,4,1...$ as $n=0,1,2,3,...$, $m^3\mod 7$ is $0,1,-1$. So $m^3\mod 7 =2^n\mod 7$ implies $n=3k$, $m\equiv 1, 2, 4\mod 7$. So you have $7p^2=2^{3k}-m^3=(2^k-m)(2^{2k}+2^km+m^2)$. Since $m^3<2^{3k}$, $m<2^k$. So $2^k-m$ is a positive divisor of $7p^2$, whence  $2^k-m=1,7,p, 7p, p^2$ or $7p^2$, and, resp. $2^{2k}+2^km+m^2=7p^2, p^2, 7p, p, 7$ or $1$. The last option is not possible. If $2^k=m+1$, then $(m+1)^2+(m+1)m+m^2=3m^2+3m+1=7p^2$, so $m\equiv 1\mod 7$, $m=7s+1$ ($m\equiv 2, 4$ are impossible since $m$ is odd). Hence
$147s^2+63s+7=7p^2$ or $21s^2+9s+1=p^2$. So $(p-1)(p+1)=3s(7s+3)$. Or $=3(2^k-2)/7(2^k+1)$. Note that $(p-1)(p+1)$ is divisible by $4$. The only way $3(2^k-2)/7(2^k+1)$ is divisible by $4$ is $k=1$. Then $m=1$  which gives $7p^2=7, p=1$, impossible.

If $2^k-m=p$, then $(m+p)^2+(m+p)m+m^2=3m^2+3mp+p^2=7p$. So $p<7$ and you can check $p=2,3,5$.
If $p=2$, $7p^2=28$, $2^{k}-m=2$, $3m^2+6m+4=14$, no integer solution. If $p=3$, then $3m^2+9m+9=21$, $m^2+3m-4=0$, $m=-4, 1$. Only $m=1$ works, $k=2$. So $n=6$. Check $2^6-(1)^3=63=9*7=3^2*7$. So $m=1, n=6$ works.

Finally, $p=5$, then $3m^2+15m+25=35$, $3m^2+15m-10=0$, no solution.

Similarly consider the cases $2^k-m=7, 7p, p^2$. For example if $2^k=m+7p$ then $(m+7p)^2+m(m+7p)+m^2=p$ which is impossible. Same for $2^k-m=p^2$.

The case $2^k-m=7$ gives
$(m+7)^2+(m+7)m+m^2=p^2$, $3m^2+21m+49=p^2$. Modulo $7$,
$m^2=0,1,4,2$, then the LHS $\equiv 0, 5, -1$ which can be $=p^2\equiv 0,4,2$ only if $p\equiv 0 \mod 7$, so $p=7$ being a prime. Hence $m=0$ or $m=-7$ but that contradicts the assumption that $m+7$ is a power of $2$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get the part of if $2^k=m+1$. Isn't that just assuming one case?

Comment: Yes, you consider the cases $2^k=m+1, m+7, m+p, m+7p, m+p^2$. The first one is the longest.

Comment: @markvs: Are there no solution?

Comment: @Piquito: Yes, I have updated the answer.

Comment: @markvs: Dear friend, you have to edit your answer because there are solutions. The problem is basically to find positive integer points of an elliptic curve with the aditional difficulty of one of them prime, so if you don't have a trick of modular arithmetic the problem is essentially hard. But, believe me please, your  "Full proof that there are no solutions" should be deleted because is wrong.

Comment: @Piquito An elliptic curve may not have integral points.  Give an example of a solution or fiind an error in the answer.

Comment: @markvs: An e. c. may not have even rational points (excepting the trivial one). I want to leave you to find yourself your error. If I were some kind of stupids I have put a downvote but I understand the effort you have put in your answer and apreciate it. Regards. (Sorry for bad English without translator).

Comment: $1^3+7\cdot3^2=2^6$

Comment: @Servaes: Yes, there was a misprint. I have fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

COMMENT.- Modulo $7$ we have $m\ne0$ so $m^6\equiv1\pmod7$ Fermat's little theorem) then  $m^3=\pm1\pmod7$ and because modulo $7$ we have $2^n=1,2\text{ or } 4$ we concluded that  the cases $2$ and $4$ must be eliminated that our equation must be (noting $3n$ instead of $n$)$$m^3+7p^2=2^{3n}\iff7p^2=(2^n-m)(2^{2n}+2^2m+m^2)$$
Since $2^n-m\lt2^{2n}+2^2m+m^2$ we must have $2^n-m=1,7\text { or } p$ (the case $2^n-m=p^2$ is discarded because it leads easily to $p=1$). Consequently we have to solve the three systems of two equations:
$$2^n-m=1\text { and } 4^n+2^nm+m^2=7p^2\hspace2cm(1)\\2^n-m=7\text { and } 4^n+2^nm+m^2=p^2\hspace2cm(2)\\2^n-m=p\text { and } 4^n+2^nm+m^2=7p\hspace2cm(3)$$ from which $(3)$ gives easily the solution $\color{red}{(m,p,n)=(1,3,6)}$ corresponding in $(3)$ to the values $n=2$ and $(p,m)=(3,1)$.

On the other hand the three equations above have infinitely many integer solutions among them it could be another solution maybe (if not at all it could be maybe proved by some trick of modular arithmetic but in fact we have essentially a problem concerning elliptic curves which are frequently very hard). I leave here this COMMENT mentioning that, for example, the system $(1)$ has the integer solutions (we ommited the solutions for $m$.
$$p=\frac{1}{28}\big((14+3\sqrt{21})(55-12\sqrt{21})^k-(14-3\sqrt{21})(55+12\sqrt{21})^k\big)$$ in which the value $k=2$ give the prime $p=109$ (the other integer corresponding to $m$ for the same exponent $k=2$ should be confronted the the proposed equation to verifiy if this gives a power of $2^3, etc, etc).$